# Filter an Array of Objects with Multiple Criteria and Partial Matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

I've found a lot of filters for arrays of objects with multiple criteria, but they seem to be exact matches. I need a way to filter for partial matches. I seem to find either one or the other.

```
let products = [
  { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: 50 },
  { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: 60 },
  { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
  { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];

let filters = {
  color: "Blue",
  size: "70"
};

function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter((item) => {
  return filterKeys.every(key => !!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key]));
  });

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
```

(https://gist.github.com/jherax/f11d669ba286f21b7a2dcff69621eb72)

I am using this function - and it works great! But the matches have to be exact. How do I change it to partial matches? And also uppercase or lowercase? I've tried lots of ways but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What would your partial match `filters` object look like?  What would you do with values that aren't strings, like the size fields?

Comment: Partial would be like `color: blu` instead of `color: Blue`, the keys would be complete, just not the values.

Comment: _"and it works great!"_ - No, it doesn't. Provide a minimal, working example/code snippet as well as expected result.

Comment: Shouldn't your filter be the other way round? `item[key]` would be the superstring and `filters[key]` would be the substring...

Comment: I think I got it working like this `return array.filter((item) => {
        return filterKeys.every(function (key) { 
            var isFilter = filters[key].toLowerCase();
            var isItem = item[key].toLowerCase();
            if (isItem.includes(isFilter)) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
      });
      });` Not very pretty but it works lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the existing code, you need to switch around the filter like @Vasan pointed out.

That means that the values of the properties in `products` will be checked to see if the values of the matching properties of `filters` are substrings.  However some of the fields in `products` are not strings.  So we'll convert them all to strings first, although I'm not sure how useful it is to search for "size: 1" and be given "size: 100" items.

```js
    let products = [
      { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: 50 },
      { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: 60 },
      { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
      { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 }
    ];
    
    let filters = {
      color: "Blu",
      size: "50"
    };

    function multiFilter(array, filters) {
      const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
      return array.filter((item) => {
        // flipped around, and item[key] forced to a string
        return filterKeys.every(key => !!~String(item[key]).indexOf(filters[key]));
      });
    }

    var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This works, but requires exact matching. The way I was fixing that is to make `var isFilter = filters[key].toLowerCase();
            var isItem = item[key].toLowerCase();` and using the variables instead. Is there a way to put it in the single line?

Comment: Oh you want case-insensitive matching.  i thought by exact matching you meant the whole word vs part of it.  Yep easy enough to fix with tolowercase, although it would be better to require the filter object to be in lowercase to start with.

Comment: Oh no, I wanted what you had as well! That's exactly what I wanted. I just also need it to be case-insensitive. lol I can get the filter to be lower case when it comes in, but I can't get the products to be lowercase.

Comment: Also, are you saying it is faster for me to do the toLowerCase on the UI instead of the API?

Comment: This worked: `return filterKeys.every(key => !!~String(item[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filters[key]));`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking for is an `Regular Expression`. you need to change

`filterKeys.every(key => !!filters[key].indexOf(item[key]))`

to be

`!filterKeys.some(key => RegExp(filters[key], 'i').test(item[key].toString()));`

of course take care using `item[key].toString()` because depending on the case it could give you a problem, in this case I used it because of the numbers (size key of the products).

```js
let products = [{
    name: "A",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 60
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    color: "Black",
    size: 70
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    color: "Green",
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    color: "bluePartial", //you are looking for blue, but blue is a substring of bluepartial, this will be filtered as well
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    color: "violet",
    size: 700 // same as above, 70 is a substring of 700
  },
];

// the value of each key is an array with the values to filter
let filters = {
  color: "Blue",
  size: "70"
};

function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter((item) => {
    return !filterKeys.some(key => RegExp(filters[key], 'i').test(item[key].toString()));
  });
}

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Using regex for a simple substring check is overkill, I think

Comment: it is not the optimal solution, but it is the one that will cover most of the cases in a simple code. I know it can be improved, but he never asked for the fastest code. hope you agree on this :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
let rows = [ { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: "50" }, { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: "60" }, { name: "C", color: "Black", size: "70" }, { name: "D", color: "Green", size: "50" }, ];

const filter = (a, f) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(f)
  if(keys.length == 1) {
    return a.filter(x => x[keys[0]].toLowerCase().includes(f[keys[0]].toLowerCase()))
  } else return a.filter(x => Object.values(f).every(fv => {
    return Object.values(x).some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(fv.toLowerCase()))
  }))
}

console.log(filter(rows, {color: "Blu", size: "50"}))
console.log(filter(rows, {color: "G", size: "5"}))
console.log(filter(rows, {name: "b"}))
console.log(filter(rows, {size: "6"}))
```

The idea is if you only have 1 filter to `filter` by the field value (otherwise `b` would match both the `name: "B"` and the `color: "Blue"` and instead of 1 result you would get 3) but if you have more than one to filter on all the values from the `filter` object.

The code uses [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to deal with the partial matches and [`String.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on the values to deal with the comparison.